# Finding random (auto) id assigned to our document by Firestore

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I know its a bit weird question but **how can I access the unique (auto) id google firebase generates for my document whenever I create new document.** For example this is my code

```
val postCollections = db.collection("posts")
val newPost = Post(text, user, currentTime)
postCollections.document().set(newPost)
```

How can I know that what is the id generated for this document of "newPost" because i want to use that id in my code and at the same time i dont want to send custom id because it won't be unique

Comment: *i dont want to send custom id because it won't be unique* Why? Use a UUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val postCollections = db.collection("posts")
val newPost = Post(text, user, currentTime)
postCollections.document().set(newPost)
```

As you've likely discovered, `.set()` returns a `Promise <void>` .

But what you've ignored is `.set()` only operates on a `DocumentReference` - which is what you get from `postCollections.document()`.  A `DocumentReference` has properties `id` and `path` -  it is the `.document()` that creates a new, unique, documentId.

So:

```
val postCollections = db.collection("posts")
val newPost = Post(text, user, currentTime)
val newRef = postCollections.document()
newRef.set(newPost)
```

And now you have the document id (and path) available as properties of newRef.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Comment: I'll note that such an id is pretty useless, except for tasks like creating a unique sub-document.  It's hard to search/query for among other issues.  It's best to structure your documents such that you query on *data* not *ids*